# crop / swap parts of image with magick mogrify

Tags: image-processing, append, imagemagick, crop, mogrify

I am trying to crop and swap different parts of a big 800x800 image and re-create 800x800 image using imagemagick with this command.

magick mogrify titli.gif -crop 2x4@ +repage -reverse -append -path converted titli.gif

my problem is "-append" creates tall image (400x1600) & "+append" creates wide image (3200x200)

How can I get a large image of original size 800x800 but with cropped and swapped (reversed) parts set in "mosaic or tiled" style...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, you shouldn't need "mogrify" to do that. Just "magick" should accomplish that task.

It looks like you'll have to crop the image into 8 pieces, reverse them, and "-append" them vertically as you've done.

Then after that, and in the same command, you'll need to crop that result in half vertically and "+append" those two pieces horizontally to get the 800x800 output.

This example command shows how it works...

```
magick in.png -crop 2x4@ -reverse -append -crop 1x2@ +append out.png
```

If you're doing any more operations within the same command you'll probably want to use "+repage" after the "+append" to reset the image geometry back to WxH+0+0.

Comment: Thanks @geemack for your response. Your command did solve problem for one image... 

I was using mogrify cos I wanted to do batch processing, 50+ images in one go, repeating this every week with different set of images...